# Don't understand why my code for prime numbers isn't working

Tags: java

```
class primeNumb {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int x;
        int m; 

        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++){    
            for (m = 0; m < 100; m++)    
                if ( (x / m == 1) && (x % m == 0) ) {    
                    System.out.println(x + "is a prime num");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

So discovering all the prime numbers under 100. The inner loop goes around 99x for each of 1 of the outer loop. During each one of these inner 99 calculations against the outer loop, it asks the questions, if division of the numbers is = to 1, if true, it asks if there is a remainder. Just like how a prime number can only be divided by itself and 1, but for that one part we don't need a calculation for. If that result is true, then the result is printed stating it as a prime number.  RIGHT?? What am I missing? The code doesn't seem to print anything but blank space. And is my logic correct?

Comment: You shouldn't be starting with 0.

Comment: What do you think `x / m == 1` is doing?

Comment: x / m == 1 is seeing if there is any other divisions. Like 5/4 = 1 but it has a mod, so then it moves onto the next, since the mod is not zero, the number passes. So it passes x in the inner loop, when it comes to 5, it will = 1 and 0, so it prints it,

Comment: Hint: the algorithm that you want will not print "is a prime" inside the inner for loop. It could, if you want, print "is not a prime" there.

Comment: You can learn a lot by pretending to be a computer, and running the code on paper.

Comment: @CharlieBrandon - I have no idea what any of your last comment means, but please think about whether it's really what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your code should look like this:

```
    for (x = 3; x < 100; x++) { // start from 3, there is no sense to check 0,1,2
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (m = 2; m < x; m++) // start from 2 and up to X
            if (x % m == 0) { // x can be divided by m -> not prime
                isPrime = false; break; // stop inner loop
            }
        if (isPrime) System.out.println("["+x+"] is prime");
    }
```

NOTE: it is not optimal way, just to show your mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Three things: 
First, if x < 3,  print out that X is a Prime,  and continue.

Second, if you are trying to find if m is a factor of x,  i.e, x % m == 0,  then X is NOT a Prime Number.

Third,  you need to check m as a factor only upto sqrt(x).  i.e., m <= sqrt(x).

Check this code.

```
public class PrimeNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++){   
            boolean isPrime = true;;
            if (x < 4) {
                System.out.println(x + " is a prime num");
                continue;
            }
            for (int m = 2; m <1+ Math.sqrt(x); m++)    {
                if ( x % m == 0)  {    
                    //System.out.println(x + " is a NOT prime num");
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime) {    
                System.out.println(x + " is  prime num");
            }
        }   

    }

}
```

Output :

```
1 is a prime num
2 is a prime num
3 is a prime num
5 is  prime num
7 is  prime num
11 is  prime num
13 is  prime num
17 is  prime num
19 is  prime num
23 is  prime num
29 is  prime num
31 is  prime num
37 is  prime num
41 is  prime num
43 is  prime num
47 is  prime num
53 is  prime num
59 is  prime num
61 is  prime num
67 is  prime num
71 is  prime num
73 is  prime num
79 is  prime num
83 is  prime num
89 is  prime num
97 is  prime num
```